# how to ping a url from sql server 2008 stored proc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hey guys, I want to ping a url over http from a sql server 2008 stored procedure.

What is the best and easiest way to do this?

UPDATE: To make it more clear, I just want to call an aspx page from a stored procedure to notify my aspx page that data has been modified and aspx needs to refresh the cache.

I know that I can do this via sql cache dependency but i want to use a push rather than a pull kind of notification.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a CLR function that accepts a host/ip address string and returns the number of seconds it took to ping, or -1 if it was unable to ping.

Comment: looks like this is the best bet :-) thnx - +1

Answer (score 2):

If you have xp_cmdshell enabled then you can use:

```
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell 'PING 127.0.0.1'
```

Make sure that you understand the security implications of enabling xp_cmdshell though. It's off by default for a reason.

Comment: security settings dont permit this unfortunately :-( anyway +1... any other way?

Comment: The CLR is probably your next best bet.

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer if you have access to xp_cmdshell.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Cache dependency *does* [use a push notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133(VS.80).aspx) via SQL Service Broker. You just need to set up your application to [subscribe to notifications](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=263&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). That would definitely be my first choice.

If for some reason that isn't suitable maybe [this approach](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/validate-a-url-from-sql-server.aspx) using Object Automation would work for you? 
**Edit** Actually I was just reading the comments under the article and the original author suggests not using this in SQL2005 but using CLR instead if it is necessary to request a URL.